# Laravel 5.6 FormRequest validation

Tags: validation, laravel-5.6

I have set of input fields to be validated. I have removed commas (since user enters comma as thousand separator) before validation takes place. But it still complains that the number is not numeric.

```
class UpdateFamilyExpense extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function sanitize()
    {
        $attributes = $this->all();

        for ($i=1; $i<=15; $i++)
        {
            $attributes['e'.$i] = str_replace(',', '', $attributes['e'.$i]);
        }
        $this->replace($attributes);
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        $this->sanitize();

        return [
            'e1' =>    'required|numeric',
        ];
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'e1.required' => 'required',
            'e1.numeric' =>  'must be a numeric',
        ];
    }
}
```

I cannot figure out where I am wrong. Can someone help me figure out what I am missing here?

Comment: After you call the `sanitize` method, you could use `dd` or `var_dump` to examine the variables manually, maybe you catch the error this way.

Comment: @Dominik Yes and I just did that too... Array had been altered correctly. `dd($this->all())` just after `$this->sanitize();`.

Comment: @Dominik I had to override `prepareForValidation()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override `prepareForValidation` as:

```
protected function prepareForValidation()
{
    $this->sanitize();
}
```